# python loop, check for previous dates

Tags: python, date

I'm using SHARADAR/DAILY data . the dataset/ data frame looks like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I97Ae.png)

i need to write a piece of code that returns the latest marketcap value.

when i write the following code...

```
    trade_date = "2021-05-16"
    df2 = quandl.get_table('SHARADAR/DAILY', ticker='AAPL', date=trade_date)
    print(df2)
```

the result is empty an dataframe

```
Series([], Name: marketcap, dtype: object)
```

i need to do two things...

1. i need it to return a single value , not a dataframe, so that i can do arithmetic calculations with it.
2. I need to create a loop that checks.. if value is empty, try to get marketcap for "trade_date" minus one day which is "2021-05-15", else return marketcap. keep minus-ing one day until we get a non-blank/ non-zero market cap

   Empty DataFrame
   Columns: [ticker, date, lastupdated, ev, evebit, evebitda, marketcap, pb, pe, ps]
   Index: []

Comment: 2021-05-16 was not a trading day, so getting an empty dataframe would be expected?

Comment: yes, thats why i need to create a "loop" to look for one day before , and get the marketcap value for the last day which was a  trading day . Could you help?

Comment: if you need loop then first create loop - and later ask questions. And you could use module `datetime` to keep date as object and use it with `datetime.timedelta(days=-1)` to get previous day.

Answer (score 0):

If you use module `datetime` to keep date as `datetime` object then you can use `datetime.timedelta(days=1)` to get previous day. And then you can run it in `while True` loop.

```
import datetime

ONE_DAY = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

day = datetime.date(2021, 5, 16)

while True:
    trade_date = str(day)
    #trade_day = day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    print(trade_date)
    day -= ONE_DAY
```

Result:

```
2021-05-16
2021-05-15
2021-05-14
2021-05-13
2021-05-12
2021-05-11
2021-05-10
2021-05-09
2021-05-08
2021-05-07
2021-05-06
2021-05-05
2021-05-04
2021-05-03
2021-05-02
2021-05-01
2021-04-30

# etc.
```

Now you can use it with your code to get expected stock data.

Comment: The code should probably stop if it runs off the beginning of the available data; some stocks are illiquid...

Comment: @sabik I show only how to create loop and get previous date(s) - rest is OP problem :)